# ggplot colour for 400+ lineplots overlayed onto each other

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data that I am trying to plot. Below I have put a `dput` of the first 500 observations, however should that not be enough, I have uploaded the .csv file on [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ab0pxouh1yr02j/combo_data.csv?dl=0).

I am trying to do two things.

Firstly change the colour scheme to a more aesthetically pleasing one. I have looked into the `scale_colour_manual` and `scale_colour_brewer` commands, but nothing is working, am I right in thinking that `colour = factor(group_id)` if overwriting these commands?

```
plot <- combo_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(ID)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = value, colour = factor(group_id))) +
  facet_wrap("type", scales = "free") +
  labs(title = "data", y = "y score", x = "x result") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 11, base_family = "") +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) + theme(legend.position="none")

plot
```

Secondly, I think it could be interesting to plot the best line in a different size and colour. What I mean by the best line is that the line which scored the highest at iteration 100 on the test data. Then put this line as black on both the test and train lines. I am not sure really where to begin on this one.

```
structure(list(type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Train", 
"Test"), class = "factor"), group_id = structure(c(75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 
95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 
95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 
95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 
95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 
95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 
95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 
95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 87L, 
87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 
87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 
87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 
87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 
87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 
87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 
87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 
87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 
198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 
198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 
198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 
198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 
198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 
198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 
198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 
198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 
198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L), .Label = c("373", 
"157", "169", "277", "61", "385", "253", "265", "361", "145", 
"37", "49", "170", "38", "266", "158", "278", "62", "146", "50", 
"374", "254", "267", "386", "362", "63", "255", "279", "51", 
"39", "375", "171", "159", "387", "363", "147", "268", "172", 
"280", "40", "376", "256", "64", "160", "52", "148", "388", "364", 
"26", "350", "242", "134", "230", "349", "122", "133", "25", 
"110", "218", "2", "14", "241", "326", "13", "229", "338", "28", 
"337", "109", "325", "352", "136", "121", "340", "1", "244", 
"217", "16", "232", "27", "328", "124", "112", "135", "351", 
"220", "4", "15", "327", "231", "243", "123", "339", "111", "3", 
"219", "281", "389", "65", "173", "392", "284", "66", "68", "390", 
"174", "176", "377", "282", "53", "67", "272", "391", "175", 
"164", "269", "54", "161", "283", "56", "162", "270", "380", 
"378", "365", "260", "41", "163", "257", "150", "368", "149", 
"271", "42", "258", "44", "379", "366", "152", "55", "259", "151", 
"367", "43", "291", "30", "356", "138", "354", "246", "32", "18", 
"140", "248", "342", "245", "353", "183", "236", "126", "128", 
"137", "234", "29", "344", "20", "222", "116", "31", "114", "224", 
"195", "6", "332", "8", "247", "330", "233", "355", "17", "341", 
"421", "409", "125", "313", "139", "73", "193", "399", "85", 
"329", "205", "181", "127", "303", "289", "343", "5", "221", 
"235", "99", "113", "97", "397", "301", "19", "423", "411", "207", 
"87", "331", "115", "315", "75", "223", "7", "206", "182", "184", 
"314", "422", "98", "410", "74", "302", "194", "208", "86", "290", 
"100", "400", "398", "424", "292", "304", "88", "412", "196", 
"316", "76", "69", "395", "285", "179", "393", "287", "71", "177", 
"72", "180", "288", "396", "273", "167", "381", "165", "383", 
"275", "57", "59", "286", "394", "178", "70", "168", "369", "384", 
"153", "60", "45", "263", "261", "276", "371", "155", "47", "58", 
"166", "382", "274", "48", "156", "264", "372", "154", "262", 
"370", "46", "317", "101", "425", "209", "141", "357", "249", 
"359", "33", "251", "35", "36", "143", "360", "144", "252", "250", 
"319", "103", "305", "89", "77", "413", "142", "211", "358", 
"197", "34", "293", "427", "401", "185", "240", "307", "24", 
"348", "132", "199", "345", "91", "415", "237", "129", "295", 
"403", "130", "187", "21", "347", "23", "239", "131", "238", 
"22", "79", "346", "12", "228", "336", "120", "225", "333", "226", 
"118", "334", "117", "9", "10", "11", "227", "335", "119", "102", 
"426", "318", "210", "428", "104", "198", "320", "414", "212", 
"306", "90", "200", "416", "308", "186", "92", "294", "402", 
"78", "404", "80", "296", "188", "105", "429", "213", "321", 
"431", "107", "323", "215", "214", "322", "106", "430", "309", 
"417", "93", "201", "432", "324", "216", "108", "419", "95", 
"311", "203", "418", "310", "202", "312", "420", "94", "96", 
"204", "405", "297", "189", "407", "81", "406", "408", "298", 
"191", "299", "300", "83", "190", "82", "84", "192"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0.841206, 0.8618822, 0.875903, 0.88118, 0.8839989, 
    0.886475, 0.8882447, 0.8894316, 0.8908262, 0.8921857, 0.8932049, 
    0.8942344, 0.8951237, 0.8957491, 0.896584, 0.8973019, 0.8981658, 
    0.8989417, 0.8996812, 0.9004134, 0.901327, 0.9018033, 0.9024117, 
    0.903043, 0.9037018, 0.9042794, 0.9048006, 0.9052915, 0.9058164, 
    0.9063951, 0.9068556, 0.9073168, 0.9078021, 0.9082714, 0.9088147, 
    0.9091887, 0.9096099, 0.909963, 0.9103733, 0.9107867, 0.9111795, 
    0.9115447, 0.9119722, 0.9123242, 0.9126455, 0.9129585, 0.9132838, 
    0.9135908, 0.9138768, 0.9141479, 0.9144209, 0.9146787, 0.914935, 
    0.9152107, 0.9154533, 0.9157019, 0.9159447, 0.9161997, 0.916484, 
    0.9167047, 0.9169661, 0.9171712, 0.9173915, 0.9176118, 0.9178227, 
    0.918049, 0.9182602, 0.9184434, 0.9186592, 0.9188716, 0.9190693, 
    0.9192857, 0.9195024, 0.9196496, 0.9198572, 0.9200831, 0.9202567, 
    0.9204585, 0.9206453, 0.9208152, 0.9210011, 0.9212046, 0.9213677, 
    0.9215177, 0.9217053, 0.9218623, 0.9220282, 0.9221877, 0.9223855, 
    0.9225362, 0.9227441, 0.9229132, 0.9230628, 0.9232101, 0.9233585, 
    0.9234887, 0.9236338, 0.9237964, 0.9239475, 0.9241024, 0.8384197, 
    0.8657936, 0.8742507, 0.8790596, 0.8816859, 0.8840703, 0.8857966, 
    0.8873143, 0.8893761, 0.8908329, 0.8924197, 0.8937073, 0.8946219, 
    0.8957115, 0.8967053, 0.8976097, 0.8983678, 0.8991453, 0.8999762, 
    0.9006377, 0.9011831, 0.9018029, 0.902479, 0.9030517, 0.9036508, 
    0.9041685, 0.9048059, 0.9053054, 0.9059556, 0.9065373, 0.9070341, 
    0.9075528, 0.9080415, 0.9086106, 0.9090282, 0.9094788, 0.909848, 
    0.9102646, 0.9106493, 0.9110334, 0.9114573, 0.9118822, 0.9122389, 
    0.9125876, 0.9129038, 0.9132206, 0.9135435, 0.9138549, 0.9141243, 
    0.9144137, 0.9147554, 0.9150141, 0.9152936, 0.9155378, 0.9158067, 
    0.9160321, 0.9162476, 0.9164621, 0.9167002, 0.9169366, 0.9171693, 
    0.91737, 0.9175802, 0.9177766, 0.9180018, 0.9182022, 0.9183998, 
    0.918624, 0.9187906, 0.9189664, 0.919135, 0.9193349, 0.9195179, 
    0.9197035, 0.9198967, 0.9200179, 0.920191, 0.9203527, 0.9205381, 
    0.9206639, 0.9207979, 0.9209801, 0.9211415, 0.9212902, 0.9214497, 
    0.9216006, 0.921792, 0.9219525, 0.9220746, 0.9222501, 0.9224183, 
    0.9225453, 0.9227172, 0.9228856, 0.9230288, 0.9231751, 0.9232918, 
    0.9234427, 0.9235908, 0.923704, 0.8521024, 0.8599692, 0.8650719, 
    0.8698721, 0.8742038, 0.8779644, 0.8805255, 0.8821768, 0.8841775, 
    0.8863809, 0.8885177, 0.8902829, 0.8918345, 0.8934113, 0.8948588, 
    0.8959888, 0.8970833, 0.8978984, 0.8988414, 0.8996618, 0.9004221, 
    0.9011989, 0.9020187, 0.9027475, 0.9034219, 0.9040693, 0.9047331, 
    0.9052631, 0.9058026, 0.906447, 0.9069784, 0.9074736, 0.9080329, 
    0.9085461, 0.9089783, 0.9094398, 0.909851, 0.910268, 0.9106672, 
    0.9110267, 0.9114393, 0.9118172, 0.9121966, 0.9125761, 0.9129089, 
    0.9132603, 0.9135873, 0.9139339, 0.9142628, 0.9145902, 0.9149295, 
    0.9152295, 0.9154791, 0.9157817, 0.9160329, 0.9162877, 0.916573, 
    0.9168525, 0.9170776, 0.9173148, 0.9175679, 0.9177926, 0.9179937, 
    0.9182309, 0.9184223, 0.9186295, 0.9188425, 0.9190884, 0.919309, 
    0.9195113, 0.91972, 0.9199461, 0.9201244, 0.9203068, 0.9204946, 
    0.9207167, 0.9208302, 0.9210215, 0.9211949, 0.9213679, 0.9215854, 
    0.9217385, 0.9219124, 0.9221097, 0.9222984, 0.9224837, 0.9226755, 
    0.9228615, 0.9230026, 0.9232086, 0.9233537, 0.9234917, 0.9236705, 
    0.9238187, 0.9239422, 0.9241217, 0.9242824, 0.9244052, 0.9245568, 
    0.9247348, 0.8530171, 0.8589155, 0.8649798, 0.869903, 0.8740718, 
    0.8779266, 0.8812847, 0.8830766, 0.8845762, 0.8865907, 0.8886054, 
    0.8900654, 0.891648, 0.893375, 0.8949505, 0.8960962, 0.8972805, 
    0.8983584, 0.8992835, 0.9001622, 0.9010127, 0.9017991, 0.9024695, 
    0.903095, 0.9037992, 0.9045072, 0.9051554, 0.9057973, 0.9064632, 
    0.9070142, 0.907557, 0.908059, 0.9085351, 0.9090597, 0.9095042, 
    0.909992, 0.9103988, 0.9108294, 0.9113101, 0.9116431, 0.9120507, 
    0.9124416, 0.9128079, 0.9131532, 0.9134848, 0.9137904, 0.9141308, 
    0.9144465, 0.9147451, 0.915065, 0.9153496, 0.9156175, 0.9158787, 
    0.9161347, 0.9163608, 0.9166158, 0.9168822, 0.9170952, 0.9173387, 
    0.9175292, 0.9177493, 0.9179786, 0.9181876, 0.9183715, 0.9185886, 
    0.918782, 0.9189904, 0.9192009, 0.9193388, 0.9195374, 0.9197003, 
    0.9198778, 0.9200472, 0.9201834, 0.920368, 0.920576, 0.9207296, 
    0.9209001, 0.9210757, 0.9212034, 0.9213856, 0.9215478, 0.9217044, 
    0.9218511, 0.9220772, 0.9222213, 0.9223657, 0.9225307, 0.9226667, 
    0.9228219, 0.9230022, 0.9231716, 0.9233128, 0.9234431, 0.9235595, 
    0.9237126, 0.923853, 0.9240294, 0.9241574, 0.9243085, 0.8718445, 
    0.8931301, 0.8988919, 0.90295, 0.9055216, 0.9073954, 0.9082992, 
    0.9094717, 0.910552, 0.9115187, 0.9123528, 0.9131647, 0.91393, 
    0.9148608, 0.9156235, 0.9163686, 0.9170021, 0.9177401, 0.9185156, 
    0.9192533, 0.9200075, 0.9207595, 0.9214583, 0.9221539, 0.9227934, 
    0.9234405, 0.9241619, 0.9247472, 0.9253838, 0.925926, 0.9265156, 
    0.9271585, 0.9277358, 0.9283588, 0.9289936, 0.9294738, 0.9299869, 
    0.9304908, 0.9309697, 0.9314306, 0.9319144, 0.9323344, 0.9327798, 
    0.9331807, 0.9336512, 0.9340747, 0.9344835, 0.9349425, 0.9353857, 
    0.9357808, 0.9361138, 0.9364561, 0.9368398, 0.9371623, 0.9375385, 
    0.9378483, 0.9382014, 0.9385149, 0.9388302, 0.9390995, 0.9394548, 
    0.9397823, 0.9401236, 0.9404473, 0.9407854, 0.9410838, 0.941425, 
    0.9417274, 0.942012, 0.9423166, 0.9426162, 0.9428458, 0.9431165, 
    0.9434549, 0.9437244, 0.9439903, 0.9442947, 0.9445493, 0.9448181, 
    0.9450798, 0.9452847, 0.9455464, 0.9458335, 0.9460275, 0.9462473, 
    0.9464572, 0.9466602, 0.9469266, 0.9471858, 0.9473951, 0.9476667, 
    0.9479168, 0.9481527, 0.9483371, 0.9485883, 0.9488048, 0.949047, 
    0.9492654, 0.9494981, 0.9497255), ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
    18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
    30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
    42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
    54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 
    66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 
    78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 
    90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
    27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
    39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
    51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
    63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 
    75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 
    87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 
    99L, 100L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
    24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
    36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
    48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 
    60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 
    72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 
    84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 
    96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
    21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
    33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
    45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 
    57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 
    69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
    81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 
    93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
    18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
    30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
    42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
    54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 
    66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 
    78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 
    90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L)), .Names = c("type", 
"group_id", "value", "ID"), row.names = c(NA, -500L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

EDIT: `xgbmodel.cv$evaluation_log` .

```
structure(list(iter = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), train_auc_mean = c(0.8783153, 
0.8953862, 0.900536, 0.9030217, 0.9049995, 0.9066914, 0.9080874, 
0.9088161, 0.9100754, 0.9108984, 0.912043, 0.9128935, 0.9137224, 
0.91465, 0.9154111, 0.9162045, 0.916924, 0.9176951, 0.9183826, 
0.9189338), train_auc_std = c(0.00717009945607681, 0.00249586501237372, 
0.00269250771585954, 0.00254956443534881, 0.00232702583784572, 
0.00181327638266765, 0.00133006362257542, 0.0013852951634466, 
0.00113504547930466, 0.00130808304018898, 0.00111638568601384, 
0.00112030141031364, 0.000975854825194455, 0.00115169779023825, 
0.00108698007799259, 0.00111895515998081, 0.00100959803891298, 
0.000955721345432234, 0.000954352681180355, 0.000932746782367693
), test_auc_mean = c(0.8679278, 0.8843016, 0.8896035, 0.8919551, 
0.8938367, 0.8955483, 0.8964231, 0.8969212, 0.8978634, 0.8986166, 
0.899632, 0.9003129, 0.9007414, 0.9013951, 0.9017771, 0.9022693, 
0.9027743, 0.9030824, 0.9035715, 0.9037952), test_auc_std = c(0.00695311168901748, 
0.00404615660101717, 0.00577139448054154, 0.0057856306907767, 
0.00606116769360227, 0.00624799443101764, 0.00538974117096598, 
0.00540648223525145, 0.00556229789206102, 0.00540702262249037, 
0.00515849813414524, 0.00518186297484329, 0.00513731438008862, 
0.00526564910433983, 0.0053733205273774, 0.00549749955981443, 
0.00561555858396273, 0.0057395095469953, 0.00560829002906322, 
0.00561293322246843)), .Names = c("iter", "train_auc_mean", "train_auc_std", 
"test_auc_mean", "test_auc_std"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000047e0788>)
```

Comment: can you define what aesthetically pleasing is implying for you. And the best line is `group_id == 5` in your example data?

Comment: over-fit much? I think you would need to provide the AUC for each line in order for us to single it out.

Comment: Well, I added the line `scale_colour_grey(start = 0.9, end = 0.1) +` which looked a little better. What I mean by aesthetically pleasing is that it becomes more clear the relationship between the  train and test plots. Adding this line, its clear that the black line on the top of the train plot, is the black line on the bottom of the test plot.

Comment: The results are "average AUC" scores over a 10-fold CV, using a grid search on different parameters. I wanted to show that the use of some parameters will significantly overfit the model while the use of other parameters will not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I would do is: plot all the curves with the same color and a low alpha (even lower than 0.1 would be good) and plot the best curve in a different color (I just picked a random one in this example).

```
library(tidyverse)
combo_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(ID)) + 
  geom_path(aes(y = value, group = group_id), color = "black", alpha =0.1) +
  facet_wrap("type", scales = "free") +
  geom_path(data = combo_data %>%
              filter(group_id == 12), aes(y = value), color = "orange")
```

[image]

I don't think you can do much better for 400 groups (unless using interactive plots (`plotly` for instance) which would allow to single out each line in both facets).

Here is the approach:

```
combo_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(ID)) + 
  geom_path(aes(y = value, group = group_id), color = "black", alpha =0.1) +
  geom_path(aes(y = value, frame = group_id), color = "orange") +
  facet_wrap("type", scales = "free") +
  labs(title = "data", y = "y score", x = "x result") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 11, base_family = "") +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) + theme(legend.position="none") ->p

library(plotly)
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Here you get a slider which you can play and it will show all the lines one by one in an animation.

EDIT1: by the way I suggest checking those ROC curves that start declining in the test set. ROC curves should not decline (by definition). **Based on the comment these are not ROC curves. Weeding out the mention of ROC from my answer.**

EDIT2: If you wish to go with a legend:

```
combo_data %>%
  mutate(what = factor(ifelse(group_id == 12,
                                 "the_one",
                                 "all_others"))) %>% #create  grouping variable
  ggplot(aes(ID)) + 
  geom_path(aes(y = value, group = group_id, color = what, alpha = what)) + #color by grouping variable and alpha by it as well
  facet_wrap("type", scales = "free") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("grey50", "orange")) + #I like this color combo
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.05, 1)) +
  guides(alpha = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1))) #so the legend is meaningful
```

[image]

to get the curve with the highest test value first find the value:

```
combo_data %>%
  filter(type == "Test") %>%
  summarise(max = max(value)) %>%
  pull(max) -> best_val
```

and then use it to label groups:

```
combo_data %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  mutate(what = factor(ifelse(any(value == best_val),
                              "the_one",
                              "all_others"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(ID)) + 
  geom_path(aes(y = value, group = group_id, color = what, alpha = what)) +
  facet_wrap("type", scales = "free") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("grey50", "orange")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.05, 1)) +
  guides(alpha = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks great, just what I was trying to acheive. One final question, the `group_id == 12` is just a random id that you plotted?

Comment: @user113156 glad to help. Yes I picked a random one, you should pick the one with the highest AUC or something like that. Edited the answer to show an even better vis. However the PC might complain.

Comment: Thanks, I found the highest AUC `data %>%
  filter(type == "Test") %>%
  filter(value == max(value))`

Comment: oh I see, the value is the AUC. I overlooked that. It seems quite obvious now.

Comment: That interative plot is pretty cool also, took some time to get going but it worked. Thanks again will save the interative plot for later use!

Comment: @user113156 by the way I suggest checking those ROC curves that start declining in the test set. ROC curves should not decline (by definition).

Comment: What I have done is firstly set many parameters using `expand.grid()` then I have a function which applies an `xgboost` model using all the parameters in the grid, which essentially creates 400+ models, for which I applied 10 fold cross validation and obtain an average score. (I know this is overkill). I then have saved in a list, 400 elements which contain the  evaluation log from the `xgboost` model, for example the average AUC score obtained across 10-fold CV which is the `y-axis`. The `x-axis` is the number of trees the model ran for (in all cases 100).

Comment: Perhaps I am completely missing something because I feel something is a little off after further inspecting it. What I have done is basically plot the `evaluation_log` of the `xgboost.cv` models. Which is an average score of 10-fold CV `evaluation_log`. I have 400 of these average `evaluation_logs`. I put a `dput` of the output I get for one of the `evaulation_logs` in the original post, so I plot `xgboost.cv$evaluation_log$train_auc_mean`.

Comment: So I hope my intuition is somewhat correct. These plots are average AUC scores and not ROC curves since I set the `eval_metric = "auc"` in the parameter list and I am just plotting these, which are averaged scores of 10-fold CV. Thanks for asking these questions, at some point I will have to defend my model and the decisions I make, so I would rather be proved wrong now than later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171603/discussion-between-missuse-and-user113156).